# How to convert specific format to any object in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nskeyedarchiver

**Current Format**

```
Optional(posterPrint.Frame(name: "RIBBA", productNumber: "303.016.24", productSize: (63.0, 93.0), pictureSize: (61.0, 91.0), pictureWithMatSize: (50.0, 70.0), frameColor: [UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.92549 0.92549 0.92549 1], matColor: [UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.92549 0.92549 0.92549 1]))
```

I want to add this one to `array` and convert any object. I tried a lot in this to stored in `NSkeyedArchiver`. I read somewhere tuples are not possible to store in `NSKeyedArchiever`. Anyone help in this

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Isn't an array for the sizes or `NSStringFromSize()` respectively an option?

Comment: You need to make you class conform to `NSCoding`. And when you do that, you'd encode/decode the tuples yourself (as separate values, as string, as custom type which itself conforms to `NSCoding`, etc.).  How to make a class conform to `NSCoding` is described in the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html).

Comment: @Rob, i wrote NSCoding class and i did everything like storing and retrieving. i want to know how to separate in this one. or can i add whole part to one array and encode /decode  could you suggest this

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "separate in this one". When I do `NSCoding` of a type, I try to make the types of the properties conform, too. Thus the object encodes its properties, and the properties themselves would conform and could therefore be encoded. And when you have an array, if the objects conform, then the array can be archived. Maybe you can show us (a) your property declarations, (b) your `encodeWithCoder` implementation; and (c) your `init?(coder:)` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To use `NSKeyedArchiver`, you make your object conform to `NSCoding`. And if you have tuples, you can encode/decode the elements separately:

```
class MyObject: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var id: Int
    var size: (Float, Float)

    init(id: Int, size: (Float, Float)) {
        self.id = id
        self.size = size

        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let id = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("id") as? Int else { return nil }
        guard let size0 = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("size.0") as? Float else { return nil }
        guard let size1 = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("size.1") as? Float else { return nil }

        self.id = id
        self.size = (size0, size1)

        super.init()
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(id, forKey: "id")
        aCoder.encodeObject(size.0, forKey: "size.0")
        aCoder.encodeObject(size.1, forKey: "size.1")
    }
}
```

You mention arrays, so I'm not sure if you're talking about an array of your custom objects, but now that your object conforms to `NSCoding`, you can now archive and unarchive arrays of these objects with no further effort.

---

Likewise, if you have some other object that has a `MyObject` property, you can apply `NSCoding` to that, and it can take advantage of the fact that `MyObject` already conforms to `NSCoding`:

```
class ParentObject: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name: String
    var value: Int
    var child: MyObject

    init(name: String, value: Int, child: MyObject) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.child = child

        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
        value = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("value") as! Int
        child = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("child") as! MyObject

        super.init()
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encodeObject(value, forKey: "value")
        aCoder.encodeObject(child, forKey: "child")
    }
}
```